# Jira - remote link using API (python)

Tags: python-3.x, api

I am using Python 3 and trying get to URL of remote link wiht JIRA issue (URL), for example in API response, https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.

```
{
    "id": 26292,
    "self": "https://jira.XXXXX.XXX/rest/api/latest/issue/TEST-1379/remotelink/26292",
    "application": {

    },
    "object": {
        "url": "https://XXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "title": "https://XXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "icon": {
            "url16x16": ""
        },
        "status": {
            "icon": {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Step one. Using

```
my_issue = 'TEST-1379'
print (jira.remote_links(my_issue))
```

I get:

```
[<JIRA RemoteLink: id=26292>, <JIRA RemoteLink: id=26734>, <JIRA RemoteLink: id=27279>, <JIRA RemoteLink: id=28150>, <JIRA RemoteLink: id=28291>]
```

Then in step 2, using:

```
print (jira.remote_link(my_issue, 26292))
```

according to documentation (http://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#jira) i thought that i will get the URL or other information, but python shows just id which was in the request...

```
26292
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<JIRA RemoteLink: id=26292>` etc. are full resources, i.e. they already contain all the fields you've shown in your JSON example.

Try this:

```
rlinks = jira_api.remote_links(issue)
import pprint; pprint.pprint(vars(rlinks[0]))
```